# Launch vsim without opening a terminal window

Tags: linux-mint, terminal, gui, .desktop

I don't know if this is very specific to `vsim` (executable of Modelsim-Altera) or not, but I will try my chance.

I have an executable which I can run by giving its path to terminal from any working directory:

```
/home/muyustan/altera/13.1/modelsim_ase/bin/vsim
```

After typing this, the following is printed to the terminal and application GUI pops up and terminal halts there.

```
Reading /home/muyustan/altera/13.1/modelsim_ase/tcl/vsim/pref.tcl
```

Now, that terminal halting there annoys me, and I know that `.desktop` files are capable of doing this without opening a terminal window if they are configured as `Terminal=false`.

However, for vsim, when I do `Terminal=false` and double click on the `.desktop` file, nothing happens. If I change it to `Terminal=true`, it works the same way of directly typing to the terminal.

So, what is the reason of this issue, is it solvable or not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Page 4 of the [VSim User Guide](http://www.txcorp.com/images/docs/vsim/latest/VSimUserGuide.pdf) discusses running VSim in Linux by running `./VSimComposer.sh` after navigating to the directory in which it's installed. Perhaps running that file from a `.desktop` file would make a difference.

Comment: @DavidYockey I will try, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Launch "/home/.../vsim -gui", with "Terminal=false".